# How to filter data from todo list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new in redux ,I  want to display filter data on todo list , if I search on any keyword its display and other data will be hidden, how can I do, please help.

This is the my todo.js file where i fetch my all todo data.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'


const Todo = () => {

    const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
    console.log(todos);

    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");



    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                    placeholder="Search Todo..."
                    value={search}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <table className="table shadow" >
                <thead>
                    <tr className="bg-danger text-white">
                        <th scope="col">Todo Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        todos.map(todo => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">{todo.id}</th>
                                    <td>{todo.title}</td>
                                    <td>Complete</td>
                                    <td><button className="btn btn-primary">View User</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo;
```

This is the store.js file where i initialize my all todos and i perform some search actionwhatever i possible

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {SEARCH_TODO} from './Action/action';


const initialState = {
    todos: [
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "delectus aut autem",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 2,
            "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 3,
            "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 4,
            "title": "et porro tempora",
            "completed": true
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 5,
            "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
            "completed": false
        }
    ]
}

const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: action.title
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(todoReducer);

export default store;
```

This is the my App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todo from './components/Todo';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Todo fetch from json</h1>
        <Todo />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where do you call dispatch your SEARCH_TODO action? I don't see it on the code. You have to dispatch an action to notify your reducer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to store it at all in the Redux state, you can instead of only mapping the todos instantly, use the filter function before that.

```
todos.filter(todo => todo.title.startsWith(search)).map(todo => {
                        return (
                            ...
                        )
                    })
```

This code assumes you want to search based on the startsWith function, but there are of course criteria that you may want to use for searching. Remember that it may be useful to first lowercase the search and the title, to make sure that even though someone capitalizes the text it's still finds the title.

Comment: The question is to learn about redux. so, your answer works but maybe not relevant to the question.